# How to change Font Size in Simulink Scope?

Tags: matlab, fonts, scope, size, simulink

I'm trying to change font size of axes, legend and title of a scope used in simulink. I've seen lots of answers for changing font size in a plot made from workspace, like using 'setgca' and 'fontsize' property, but couldn't find anything about changing font size within a simulink scope.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried couple methods, but there's no direct way to implement this. However, we could adjust the font size of titles and x/y labels inside the Figure associated with scope

1. Directing to scope to figure
   After you run the scope, click the scope. In the task bar, select

   File > Print to Figure

This will bring you to a figure where we can edit figure's fonts.

2. Edit font inside the figure

   Edit > Figure Properties

   In the pop-up window, edit the font.

Comment: What worked for me: Follow the above steps to open the Figure Properties dialog and close it again to make the figure clickable. Right-click the figure and choose `Font...`. After changing the font, drag at the edge of the figure to resize it to adjust the margins.

Answer (score 0):

In simulink is possible to change the font style and size using going to:

> Diagram > Format > Font Styles for Model

There you can change the font style and size for blocks, lines and annotations.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any functionality to change these from a pulldown menu, however, they can all be changed using code.

The primary thing to note is that a Simulink Scope is just a MATLAB Figure Window in disguise, and hence it can be manipulated using standard Handle Graphics commands once you have the handle to the scope block you want to manipulate.

For instance to change the size of the legend you'd do:

```
% Get the Name of the block you want to change
scope_name = get_param(gcb,'Name');
% Get the handle of the figure window used for the scope
hs = findall(0,'Tag','SIMULINK_SIMSCOPE_FIGURE','Name',scope_name);
% Get the handle to the axes on the scope
% (For simplicity, here we'll assume there is only one axis on the scope.
% If there are multiple axes, then you'll need to select which one to manipulate.)
ha = findall(hs,'Type','Axes');
% Get the handle to the legend
hl = get(ha,'Legend');
% Change the font size
set(hl,'FontSize',12);
```

Given any of the above handles you can manipulate it using `set` and `get` just like any Handle Graphics object.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how to access the scope object from MATLAB, however, I managed to change the **legend** and **titles** text sizes by simply resizing the scope window. I know it's not exactly the right way to do this but it works.